# Spring OpenApi server URLS in Spring Gateway

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have several microservices that are registered in Eureka. I implemented the gateway to centralize all the swagger documentations.

The issue is the following:

1. On each micro services I can access the Swagger documentation and everything works fine. We can note that the generated server's URL returns the current server IP.

[image]

2. On the other side, In my gateway, I try to centralize my openapi documentations and I noticed that generated servers URL are 'localhost'. It wouldn't be a problem if it was working on a single machine.

[image]

**My issue is the following:**

- How can i set dynamically the base URL used in the gateway ? for example, here i would like to get the current IP instead of the localhost.
- Actually, my gateway is calling to localhost instead of server

**Here is my application.yml configuration for my gateway:**
I didn't find how to set URLs dynamically yet.

```
server:
  port: 8060
  forward-headers-strategy: framework

spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    username: guest
    password: guest
    port: 5672
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:${CONFIG_SERVER:http://localhost:8888}"
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          useInsecureTrustManager: true
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
        - id: openapi
          uri: http://${DEPLOYMENT_SERVER:localhost}:${server.port}
          predicates:
            - Path=/v3/api-docs/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/v3/api-docs/(?<path>.*), /$\{path}/v3/api-docs

        - id: users
          uri: lb://users-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/users-service/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/users-service/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}

        - id: dsipilot-config
          uri: lb://config-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/config-service/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/config-service/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
      default-filters:
        - "DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"
        - "AddResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin, *"
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowed-origin-patterns: '*'
            allowed-methods: '*'
            allowed-headers: '*'
            exposed-headers:
              - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
              - Authorization
              - Content-Type
              - Origin
              - x-access-token
              - userId

springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    use-root-path: true
    configUrl: /v3/api-docs/swagger-config
    url: /v3/api-docs
    urls:
      - name: users
        url: /v3/api-docs/users-service
  cache:
    disabled: true


eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

logging:
  pattern:
    level: '%5p [${spring.application.name}, %X{traceId:-}, %X{spanId:-}]'
    dateformat: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
    file: '%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger.%M - %msg%n'
    console: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %green([%thread]) %highlight(%level)  %logger - %msg%n'
  file:
    name: webapps-logs/cloud-gateway-service.log
  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
      max-history: '5'
      max-file-size: 1250MB
  level:
    root: WARN
    fr.dsidiff: INFO
    org.springframework: INFO

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        #include: openapi, swagger-ui, busrefresh
        include: '*'
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
      show-details: always
      #circuitbreakers:
      # enabled: true
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1
  zipkin:
    tracing:
      endpoint: http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
```

Comment: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/108#issuecomment-789709745 may help, if it does not I can delete the comment later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added to each micro service the @OpenApiDefinition annotation with the following information :

@OpenAPIDefinition(

```
servers = { @Server(url = "/webservice-uri", description = "Default Server URL") },
info = @Info(
        title = "My API",
        version = "1.0.0",
        description = "My API v1.0"))
```

here /webservice-uri matches with the route defined in the gateway, for example:

```
gateway:
  httpclient:
    ssl:
      useInsecureTrustManager: true
  discovery:
    locator:
      enabled: true
      lower-case-service-id: true
  routes:
    - id: dummy
      uri: lb://dummy-service
      predicates:
        - Path=/webservice-uri/**
      filters:
        - RewritePath=/webservice-uri/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

and here:

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    use-root-path: true
    configUrl: /v3/api-docs/swagger-config
    url: /v3/api-docs
    urls:
      - name: dummy
        url: /v3/api-docs/webservice-uri
```